# Why is my code returning a ValueError when I attempt to assign a value to a new instance?

Tags: django, post, django-views, instance

I'm getting the following error when attempting to create a "Player" instance using the "user" and a "town" in which they chose to settle through submitting a form with POST.

```
ValueError at /town/create_player/
Cannot assign "[<Town: Citytown>]": "Player.town" must be a "Town" instance.
```

This confuses me, because it looks like Town: Citytown **is** a "Town" instance. What am I missing ?

Here is my views.py code :

```
if request.method == 'POST': # check if post data has been sent through the join town page
    town_slug = request.POST.get('town_to_join')
    town = Town.objects.filter(slug=town_slug)
    user = request.user
    new_player = Player(town=town, user=user)
    new_player.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/town/')
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with this line

```
town = Town.objects.filter(slug=town_slug)
```

The `.filter()` returns queryset not an object instance.

You can use `.get()`

```
town = Town.objects.get(slug=town_slug)
```

But take appropriate precaution that `.get()` may raise exception when its not found.

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` returns a `QuerySet` because it can return more than one item.  You can tell its not an object because in its representation it looks like a list `[<Town: Citytown>]`.

To get the individual object out you need to refer to it by its index:

```
if request.method == 'POST': # check if post data has been sent through the join town page
    town_slug = request.POST.get('town_to_join')
    town = Town.objects.filter(slug=town_slug)
    user = request.user
    new_player = Player(town=town[0], user=user) # get the first town that matches the slug
    new_player.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/town/')
```